# UIViewControllers default swipe left event

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is possible to disable/enable the default swipe left event for popviewcontroller.For example i'm using the default "Master Detail Application" template when i'm touching DetailViewController swipes left at the master view.How is this implemented?

Comment: set the `animated:` property to no, will give you no animation. Are you trying to set a custom animation?

Comment: no i just want the default behavior for an app but doesnt work when i push a view to master view controller i want to pop out with swipe without using the back button any ideas?

Comment: Add a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the view?

Comment: I updated my answer, as the original had an error. Try it out & tell me if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: 5 hours later and I still don't know if my answer worked... People these days... *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a UISwipeGestureRecognizer, like so:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeBack = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(popView)];
swipeBack.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeBack.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeBack];
```

And just put that where you want to perform the gesture. A safe place would be in the `viewDidLoad` of the VC you want to swipe back FROM.

Make sure that you include a method to define the selector `popView`. It would be like this:

```
- (void)popView
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```